# Reactjs: don't let Modal trigger a re-render

Tags: reactjs

In my `Reactjs` project I have a component that contains a Modal that has its own states and when 1 (or more) of these states change, they trigger a re-render of that component:

```
import React from "react";
import CustomModalComponent from "./CustomModalComponent";

const MainComponent = () => {
  const [isModalOpen,setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  console.log("main component");

  return(
      <React.Fragment>
         <section>Some UI here that can also turn modal state to true</section>
         <CustomModalComponent open={isModalOpen} toggleOpen={() => setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)} />
      </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default MainComponent;
```

As I said whenever a state changes inside that custom modal component, it triggers a re-render in my main component which is due to the fact that I have a state that changes, but I was wondering if there is a way to change this "behavior" since if my main component is a big one, re-renders will take away from the performance.

Comment: React is designed that way. It is no necessary to worry re-render until you really meet a performance problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about rerenders until they are a problem. It is a common beginner's error to optimize for reducing rerenders. Sadly, a lot of false material exists online around this that suggests you need to be thinking about this from day 1. Rerenders are usually extremely cheap and simply don't matter.

Keep in mind a "rerender" doesn't mean it loads all the HTML up again in the DOM. Internally React diffs over the state, meaning it only makes small edits when the state changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "until they are a problem"?

Comment: @Daniel_Kamel It means that unless you see a problem caused by those rerenders (e.g. performance issues), there's nothing you need to do -- rerenders per se are a perfectly normal implementation detail. Also, many issues that get blamed on re-renders often come down to incorrect lifecycle management (e.g. some side effect is triggered on every render instead of only during initial mount or when dependencies change).

Comment: Correct. Basically, they are a problem only if you notice that when a rerender happens there is visibly lag on the UI or some issue with the performance of user interactions. As @ij7 correctly implies, this is also often about making rerenders cheaper in that situation, and not eliminating them.